# How to prove vectors are linearly independent based on determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, vectors, determinant

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Prove that the vectors $\vec{\text{u}}_1$, $\vec{\text{u}}_2$, and $\vec{\text{u}}_3$ are linearly independent if and only if
>   $$ \det \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \\ x_3 & y_3 & z_3 \end{bmatrix} \neq 0 $$

I'm having trouble choosing which direction to go about. I'm aware of the following:

- The above determinant is equivalent to the triple product of said vectors:
  $$ \vec{\text{u}}_1 \cdot (\vec{\text{u}}_2 \times \vec{\text{u}}_3) $$
- The three above vectors are linearly independent if the equation
  $$ a_1 \vec{\text{u}}_1 + a_2 \vec{\text{u}}_2 + a_3 \vec{\text{u}}_3 = 0 $$
  has only the trivial solution.
- Any two vectors are linearly independent if their dot product is equal to 0.

---

My first attempt was to use the three combinations of dot products to create the following system :
\begin{gather*}
a_1 x_1 x_2 + a_1 y_1 y_2 + a_1 z_1 z_2 = 0 \\
a_2 x_1 x_3 + a_2 y_1 y_3 + a_2 z_1 z_3 = 0 \\
a_3 x_2 x_3 + a_3 y_2 y_3 + a_3 z_2 z_3 = 0
\end{gather*}
and somehow work it into the determinant, but I feel like this isn't the correct way to do it.

Another idea was to use Sarrus' rule on the determinant to obtain a new equation through which I could work my way up to the second bullet point, but that doesn't seem to make any sense.

Maybe I can't see the forest for the trees; I'm not really good at linear algebra proofs. I'm just looking for a hint to go in the right direction.

Comment: Don't know that you are allowed to use that, but it's well known that the corresponding [Homogeneous linear system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems) with non-0 determinant has only the trivial zero solution.

Comment: Intuitively, $ \vec{\text{u}}_1 \cdot (\vec{\text{u}}_2 \times \vec{\text{u}}_3) \neq 0$ means that $\vec{\text{u}}_1$ is not orthogonal to $\vec{\text{u}}_2 \times \vec{\text{u}}_3$. In other words, $\vec{\text{u}}_1$ is not in the same plane defined by $(\vec{\text{u}}_2, \vec{\text{u}}_3)$, which implies that $\vec{\text{u}}_1$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of the other two vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write the vectors as *column* vectors. A linear relation between $\vec u_1, \vec u_2$  and $\vec u_3$ can be written matricially as
$$A\begin{bmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\a_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2&x_3\\ y_1 & y_2&y_3\\z_1 & z_2&z_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Now multiply both sides  on the left by the *adjugate* matrix of $A$:
$$\operatorname{adj}(A)\,A\begin{bmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\a_2\end{bmatrix}= \det A\: I_3\begin{bmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\a_2\end{bmatrix}=\det A\begin{bmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\a_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
As $\det A\neq 0$, this implies
$$\begin{bmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\a_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Is $u_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$?

Comment: Absolutely. $ $

Comment: Ha, that's how I tried next, except I had forgotten about transposing the coordinate matrix. Thanks!