# Compute a scalar such that the set given is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let vector set $\{u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4\}$ is linearly independent.  The vector set $\{u_1+au_2, u_2+au_3, u_3+au_4, u_4+au_1\}$ is also linearly independent if the value of $a = \cdots$

I have applied the definition of linearly independent vectors in the set, but found a hard way when dealing with the second vector set, assuming that we have $k_1 = k_2 = k_3 = k_4 = 0$ from the first one. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But, how about the step?

Comment: Can you extend the logic in the linked question to 4 dimensions and answer yourself? Essentially you need a particular determinant to be non-zero.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941373/how-to-prove-vectors-are-linearly-independent-based-on-determinant

Answer (score 1):

Since the first set of vectors is linearly independent, it forms a basis for the set’s span. The coordinates of the second set of vectors relative to this basis are $[1,a,0,0]^T$ etc. The vectors are linearly independent iff the determinant of the matrix that has these coordinate vectors as its columns (or rows) is nonzero. The latter matrix is, not coincidentally, also the coefficient matrix of the system of linear equations in [Dr. Graubner’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2686443/265466).

Answer (score 0):

make the ansatz $$\alpha(\vec{u_1}+a\vec{u_2})+\beta(\vec{u_2}+a\vec{u_3})+\gamma(\vec{u_3}+a\vec{u_4})+\delta(\vec{u_4}+a\vec{u_1})=\vec{0}$$ where $$\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$$ are real numbers 
then you will get
$$\alpha+a\delta=0$$
$$\alpha a+\beta=0$$
$$\beta a+\gamma=0$$
$$\gamma a+\delta=0$$

Comment: then what should be the next step?